# How to deal with this error?json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have looked over as many similar questions with the same error but cannot seem to find a solution. Can someone lead me to a solution?
I am running into this error while executing my code...the error is as follows:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is my code:

```
IMAGEDATA = json.loads(open("imagedata.json",'r').read())
```

The JSON file is as follows:

```
["-533479225","1190868050","-858804567","-478770949","34712964","-880781543","867322169","991305586","-316899420"]
```

The entire stack trace is:

```
File "C:\Users\britl\source\repos\FLASHBOT\FLASHBOT\Nike\nikesensor.py", line 9, in <module>
    IMAGEDATA = json.load(open("imagedata.json",'r')).read()
  File "C:\Users\britl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\britl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\britl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\britl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Try a `print(open("imagedata.json",'r').read())`and see what you find. It looks like `json.loads()` is complaining that you passed it a None value.

Comment: `open("imagedata.json",'r').read()` almost certainly isn't returning any data and `json.loads()` expects to receive valid JSON.

Comment: @MichaelR I just tried that and it does print my json file then continues with the rest of my code. So how do i fix it so its not a None?

Comment: If that's true then json.loads() should not throw that error. Try this out and let me know what you get `print(open("imagedata.json",'r').read()) jsondata = open("imagedata.json",'r').read() IMAGEDATA = json.loads(jsondata)` edit: posting as answer for formatting purposes.

Comment: @MichaelR ran that and it brings me back to my first error

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see if it leads you to the issue at hand. It appears that json.loads() is somehow receiving a None value.

```
import json

jsondata = open("imagedata.json",'r').read() 
print(jsondata) 
IMAGEDATA = json.loads(jsondata)
print(IMAGEDATA)
```

[here's a repl.it](https://repl.it/@DoloMike/WildSecondaryPixel) - make `imagedata.json` empty and you'll see the same error.

Comment: The repl.it prints two empty ones